# Why do a lot of projects only offer source and no jars for download?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I've seen a lot of projects, even from big companies like [Elephant Bird (Twitter)](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/) and [Akela (Mozilla)](https://github.com/mozilla-metrics/akela) that offer source and ask you to compile it yourself instead of also offering jars. Is there some benefit to compiling in your own environment instead of just downloading a jar someone else has compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Dependencies are not in the same location or even have the same version on every machine. It is simpler to detect where they are at compile-time.
2. If there is any native code (sometimes just for optimization) in a project, there are probably platform-dependent flags that need to be set at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is [dependency management](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-build-tools-how-dependency-management-works-with-maven-gradle-and-ant-ivy/). Most public OSS Java projects offer jars by publishing them to [Maven Central](http://central.sonatype.org/). You are expected to use a build system like [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org), [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy), or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) to manage your dependencies - these tools will automatically download the library you want along with any of its dependent libraries and be smart about it, caching it on your local filesystem so if a library is shared across multiple libraries it won't be downloaded twice.

As for the example projects you listed, Elephant Bird [is available via Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Celephant-bird) whereas Akela tells you exactly how to create your own jar (perhaps it's not quite far along enough to justify going through the rigmarole of [publishing to Maven Central](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)):

```
Building

To make a jar you can do:

mvn package

To make a Hadoop MapReduce job jar with no defined main class in the manifest:

mvn assembly:assembly
```

Comment: I know how to create the jars. The question is why. Your answer applies if I have to use Java for the project anyway, but if I just need the JAR for some other language (like Pig in the examples), why would I want to compile instead of just downloading a jar?

Answer (score 1):

Without an automatic build system its hard to maintain a current version of the jar file online. Including the jar file in the repository is generally not a good idea as users who clone it don't need the compiled jar, they want the code. So unless the publisher explicitly adds a jar file to a download location outside of the sourcecode repository and updates this file every time the application changes you have to compile it yourself. Automatic Build systems can help a publisher to provide a current compiled jar to it's users but for smaller projects it's not always sufficient to go through the trouble of setting one up.